# Python reverse list in iterator

Tags: python, list, reverse

I am looking to create two dictionaries from a list of nested lists:

```
M = {index of list: list}

N = {index of list: reversed list}
```

Example:

For starters I have the following list:

```
L =  [[20, 56], [23, 24], [23, 12], [22, 21], [26, 48], [26, 24]]
```

so the end result would be:

```
M = {0: [56, 20], 1: [24, 23], 2: [12, 23], 3: [21, 22], 4: [48, 26], 5: [24, 26]}
N = {0: [20, 56], 1: [23, 24], 2: [23, 12], 3: [22, 21], 4: [26, 48], 5: [26, 24]}
```

I have tried this out:

```
M = {}
N = {}
for index, pair in enumerate(L):
    M[index] = pair
    N[index] = pair.reverse()
```

but the result of this is:

```
M = {0: [56, 20], 1: [24, 23], 2: [12, 23], 3: [21, 22], 4: [48, 26], 5: [24, 26]}
N = {0: [56, 20], 1: [24, 23], 2: [12, 23], 3: [21, 22], 4: [48, 26], 5: [24, 26]}
```

I have solved it by doing:

```
N[index] = pair[::-1]
```

but could someone please tell me why this is happening?

Comment: I'm not sure I believe your results.  `.reverse()` acts in-place and returns `None`, so shouldn't you get `N == {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None}`?

Answer (score 5):

`list.reverse` is an in-place operation, as keys in both dicts point to the same object so all references are affected.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> a.reverse()
>>> a
[3, 2, 1]
>>> b
[3, 2, 1]
```

To get a new reversed copy of a list you can use `a[::-1]` or `list(reversed(a))`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a[::-1]
>>> b is a
False
>>> b = list(reversed(a))
>>> b is a
False
```

But `a[::-1]` should be always preferred over `list(reversed(a))` if you want a reversed list, if you want an iterator go for `reversed(a)`.

Comment: ok gotcha. I forgot that a name and an object are not the same in python.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @hcwhsa `list.reverse` will do a in place which will modify the list. If you don't want to do the in place you could do the following:

```
>>> l[::-1]
[3, 2, 1]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to get a list/string/tuple in reverse order is a[::-1].  That returns the elements of a from last to first, as a copy--without modifying a.